# Substituting Conditional Value $P(X+Y = s | Y = y)$ when conditioning on a random variable

Tags: random-variables, conditional-probability

For conditional random variable, I have seen the formula $P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$. But I have also noticed, especially when conditioning on random variables, one just "subs in" the condition into the argument of the probability. What is the justification behind this / when can we do this?

For example:
If I have
$$P(X+Y=s |Y=y)$$
I would just "sub in" $Y=y$ into the argument and say $P(X+y=s|Y=y)$,

What allows me to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$\Pr\left(X+Y=s|Y=y\right) = \frac{\Pr\left(X+Y=s \text{ and } Y=y\right)}{\Pr\left(Y=y\right)}.$$
Now, the system of equations $X+Y=s$ and $Y=y$ is equivalent to $X+y=s$ and $Y=y$. As such, we have
$$\Pr\left(X+Y=s|Y=y\right) = \frac{\Pr\left(X+y=s \text{ and } Y=y\right)}{\Pr\left(Y=y\right)}  = \Pr\left(X+y=s |Y=y \right).$$

Comment: Thank you @Math Lover!